# Will assigning network to one service isolate it from other services in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have many services running and sharing the default network.

Now I want to create integrationTest container that will be isolated from the default network, so I can test haProxy as well.

```
  integration-test:
    image: image:some-image:tag
    container_name: integration-test
    command: node_modules/.bin/jest integration/
    networks:
      - frontend
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

Is it enough to assign network to this service, thus segregating it from other services or do I need to assign another network to all other services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; Yes that will separate integration-test from any other services in your docker-compose file.

The longer version...

By default docker-compose creates a bridge network for your docker-compose.yml file in the pattern of `project_default` (AKA the default network).

The following two service definitions are exactly the same.

```
app:
  build: .
  networks:
    - default

app:
  build: .
```

If you want your service to connect to an additional network then you have to list both `default` as well as the other network.

```
app:
  build: .
  networks:
    - default
    - frontend
```

If you want your service to ONLY be on the other service then just remove `default` from networks.

```
app:
  build: .
  networks:
    - frontend
```

If you are ever in doubt as to what containers are connected to what networks you can always inspect the container or network. eg. `docker inspect frontend` or `docker inspect project_app_1`